# Quick way to determine existence of integral root of a polynomial in one variable

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Suppose $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and if there exist $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $p(b)=0$, then $x-b|p(x)$. The other technique can be to put all $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But this require to check every $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite set.

So is there a quick way of determining whether or not there exist such $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $p(x)=(x-b)f(x)$ for some polynomial $f(x)$...

Product of constant term of $f$ and $-b$ should be same as constant term of $p$.

Thus, $b$ should divide constant term...

So, it is enough to check for factors of $p(0)$..

Answer (score 1):

> But this require to check every b∈ℤ where ℤ is an infinite set.

False. Only is required check the divisors ($+$ and $-$) of $p(0)$.

Comment: Can you explain why to check only the divisors of the constant term?

Comment: @user110219, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem.